# Python string replacement with random items

Tags: python, regex, string

[String replacement in Python](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) is not difficult, but I want to do something special:

```
teststr = 'test test test test'
animals = ['bird','monkey','dog','fox']
#replace 'test' with random item from animals
finalstr = ['dog fox dog monkey']
```

I write a very inefficient version:

```
from random import choice
import string
import re

teststr = 'test test test test'
animals = ['bird','monkey','dog','fox']

indexes = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('test', 'test test test test')]
#indexes = [0, 5, 10, 15]
for i in indexes:
    string.replace(teststr, 'test', choice(animals), 1)

#Final result is four random animals
#maybe ['dog fox dog monkey']
```

It works, but I believe there is some simple method with REGULAR EXPRESSION which I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [re.sub callback](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
import random

animals = ['bird','monkey','dog','fox']

def callback(matchobj):
    return random.choice(animals)

teststr = 'test test test test'
ret = re.sub(r'test', callback, teststr)
print(ret)
```

yields (for example)

```
bird bird dog monkey
```

The second argument to `re.sub` can be a string or a function (i.e. a callback). If it is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrance of the regex pattern, and its return value is substituted in place of the matched string.

Comment: I dont know who delete the "lambda" verson: `re.sub(r'test', lambda m: random.choice(animals), teststr)` Actually it seems to be more succinct.

Comment: @GabySolis I deleted it (it was my answer). I thought the answer was unneccesary since unutbu already answered your question some seconds before me, basically saying the same: use re.sub with a callback. But if you like it, I undelete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> import re
>>> teststr = 'test test test test'
>>> animals = ['bird','monkey','dog','fox']
>>> re.sub('test', lambda m: choice(animals), teststr)
'fox monkey bird dog'
>>> re.sub('test', lambda m: choice(animals), teststr)
'fox dog dog bird'
>>> re.sub('test', lambda m: choice(animals), teststr)
'monkey bird monkey monkey'
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do the job:

```
import random, re
def rand_replacement(string, to_be_replaced, items):
    return re.sub(to_be_replaced, lambda x: random.choice(items), string )
```